# .Post in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

im using the below code in jquery, but my page itself reloading, i dont know where i have made a mistake.

```
var newstr = $.trim($('#umail').val());
```

newstr holds the email address

```
$.post("coding/unsub.php",{email:newstr},function(result){
$("#d_result").html(result);
});
```

i have

```
<span id="d_result"></span>
```

to show the result

my php code is

```
<?php
include ("../includes/dbcon_.php");
$unsub_sql = mysql_query("Delete FROM TblNewsLetter WHERE Email = '$_GET[email]'");
if (!$unsub_sql)
{
    $ds_result = "<p style='font-size:200%;color:red;'>Some Error Occurred! Try Later.</p>";
}
else
{
    $ds_result = "<p style='font-size:200%;color:green;'>Successfully Unsubscribed</p>";
}
mysql_close($con);
echo $ds_result;
?>
```

Comment: How do you call the `$.post()` code? Is it in a function called on submit of a form?

Comment: Most likely you aren't suppressing the default behavior of the `<a>` link or have an error in the JavaScript somewhere and default behavior suppressing doesn't work. Try changing the `<a>` to `<span>` for example and watch the JS error console for messages.

Comment: You may add a "die()" or "exit()" at the end of your PHP code, just in case.
Also install Firebug (Firefox Extension) open the console and check whether some strange requests are made.
Also where do you call the $.post() ? at document.ready() ?

Comment: nnnnn i call the code on form submit.

Comment: Yeah well obviously you do not suppress the native submit behaviour so the form gets sent and the page reloads

Comment: Either you add your javascript to the forms action attribute or you add
$('form').on('submit', function(event){event.preventDefault});

Comment: deomonfire300, thanks for your reply, let me try that and tell you.

Comment: Its works fine after adding $('form').on('submit', function(event){event.preventDefault}); thank for spending your valuable time regarding my issue doemonfire and rest of you too.

Answer (score 2):

You said in a comment that you do the Ajax call from a form submit handler. You need to prevent the default submit behaviour, either by using the event object's [`.preventDefault()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or by returning `false` from the handler:

```
$("#yourFormSelectorHere").submit(function(e) {
    var newstr = $.trim($('#umail').val());

    $.post("coding/unsub.php",{email:newstr},function(result){
        $("#d_result").html(result);
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    // and/or
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sql query

```
$mail = $_GET['email'];
$query = "DELETE FROM TblNewsLetter WHERE Email = $mail";
```

`$_GET` should be changed to `$_POST`

Comment: brian, thanks for your reply. i have changed too, but its  not working. the problem im facing is not with php, my code is working perfect.

Comment: If the problem is not with PHP, why are you showing the PHP code? Show the HTML/JS that handles the AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$unsub_sql = mysql_query("Delete FROM TblNewsLetter WHERE Email = '".$_POST['email']."'");
```